# Prove that $m+\frac{4}{m^2}\ge3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to prove that $m+\frac{4}{m^2}\geq3$ for every $m>0$? I multiplied both sides by $m^2$ and finally got $m^3+4-3m^2\geq0$, yet don't know how to move further. Hint?

Comment: If $m\geq3$ then $m+\frac{4}{m^2}>m\geq3$. If $m=1$ then $m+\frac{4}{m^2}=1+4>3$. If $m=2$ then $m+\frac{4}{m^2}=2+1=3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or if you want different approach from AM-GM inequality

$m^3-3m^2+4=m^3-2m^2-m^2+4=m^2(m-2)-(m-2)(m+2)=(m-2)(m^2-m-2)=(m-2)^2\cdot (m+1)$

since $m+1>0$ , and $(m-2)^2 \geq 0$ , we are done. Equality occurs when $m=2$

Comment: Don't you mean $(m-2)^2\cdot (m+1)$?

Comment: You are right, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For quite a different approach, you could differentiate $f(m)=m+\frac{4}{m^2}$ w.r.t. $m$, resulting in $f'(m)=1-\frac{8}{m^3}$.

Setting $f'(m)$ to zero and solving for $m$ results in $m=2$, so that the minimum is $3$ (given that the second derivative $f''(m)=\frac{24}{m^4}$ is positive for $m=2$).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use $a+b+c\ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$ for $a=b=\frac m{2},c=\frac{4}{m^2}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, you are right.

Comment: Interestingly, this hint proves the case where $m$ is any positive real number, not just the natural numbers scenario.  This hint relies on knowledge of the relationship between the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean.  Putting this link here for @poorman to read if he hasn't seen it before.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 2):

If $m=1$, then

$$m + \frac{4}{m^2}= 1 + \frac{4}{1^2} = 1 + 4 = 5 \geq 3$$

If $m = 2$, then

$$m + \frac{4}{m^2} = 2 + \frac{4}{2^2} = 2 + 1 = 3 \geq 3$$

Consider now $m\geq 3$. Then, since $\frac{4}{m^2}$ is positive for all $m$, it is obvious that also $m + \frac{4}{m^2}$ is greater than $3$.

We can conclude that

$$m + \frac{4}{m^2}\geq 3 ~ \forall m > 0$$

Comment: If m can equal any other value between 0 and 1, is it enough to show that is holds for 1, 2, and any value >=3?

Comment: No.  This argument only works $\{1,2\}\cup\{x:x\ge 3\}$.... though it is very close to being complete.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I just wondered that $m$ was an integer number.

Answer (score 1):

$$m^3-3m^2+4\geq 0$$

now we assume the $$f(m)=m^3-3m^2+4$$

the  minimum value of function $f(m)$ as follows
$$f'(m)=3m^2-6m=0$$
$$3m(m-2)=0$$ 
$$m_1=0$$
$$m_2=2$$
the $m_2=2$ gives the minimum value which is $f(2)=0$ if $m\geq0$, 
so the $f(m)$ must be equal or greater than $0$

Answer (score 1):

Using $A.M\geq G.M$

$$\frac{\frac{m}{4}+\frac{m}{4}+\frac{m}{4}+\frac{m}{4}+\frac{m}{4}+\frac{2}{m^2}+\frac{2}{m^2}}{6}\geq\frac{1}{2}$$

$$m+\frac{4}{m^2}\geq3$$

Equality occurs if

$$\frac{m}{4}=\frac{m}{4}=\frac{m}{4}=\frac{m}{4}=\frac{m}{4}=\frac{2}{m^2}=\frac{2}{m^2}$$

$i.e.$ for $m=2$